# Validation of one variable can't be equal to other variable not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a validation that won't let the user insert when the values are the same but whenever I'm trying to insert it normally (every data is different) it's not inserting.

Here's my code and the problem is with the if and else if. The insert is working without the ifs and else but I need to put a validation that wont let me insert when the values are the same.

```
<?php


$url='Settings.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submitanswertype'])) {

    $radio1 = $_POST['radio1'];
    $radio2 = $_POST['radio2'];
    $radio3 = $_POST['radio3'];
    $radio4 = $_POST['radio4'];
    $radio5 = $_POST['radio5'];
    $radio6 = $_POST['radio6'];
    $radio7 = $_POST['radio7'];
    $radio8 = $_POST['radio8'];
    $radio9 = $_POST['radio9'];
    $radio10 = $_POST['radio10'];
    $answerype = $_POST['answertype'];

    $answer = new CategoryDAO();

        if($radio1 == $radio2 || $radio1 == $radio3 || $radio1 == $radio4 || $radio1 == $radio5 || $radio1 == $radio6 || $radio1 == $radio7 || $radio1 == $radio8 || $radio1 == $radio9 || $radio1 == $radio10)
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else if($radio2 == $radio1 || $radio2 == $radio3 || $radio2 == $radio4 || $radio2 == $radio5 || $radio2 == $radio6 || $radio2 == $radio7 || $radio2 == $radio8 || $radio2 == $radio9 || $radio2 == $radio10)
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else if($radio3 == $radio1 || $radio3 == $radio2 || $radio3 == $radio4 || $radio3 == $radio5 || $radio3 == $radio6 || $radio3 == $radio7 || $radio3 == $radio8 || $radio3 == $radio9 || $radio3 == $radio10)
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else if($radio4 == $radio1 || $radio4 == $radio2 || $radio4 == $radio3 || $radio4 == $radio5 || $radio4 == $radio6 || $radio4 == $radio7 || $radio4 == $radio8 || $radio4 == $radio9 || $radio4 == $radio10)
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else if($radio5 == $radio1 || $radio5 == $radio2 || $radio5 == $radio3 || $radio5 == $radio4 || $radio5 == $radio6 || $radio5== $radio7 || $radio5 == $radio8 || $radio5 == $radio9 || $radio5 == $radio10)
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else if($radio6 == $radio1 || $radio6 == $radio2 || $radio6 == $radio3 || $radio6 == $radio4 || $radio6 == $radio5 || $radio6 == $radio7 || $radio6 == $radio8 || $radio6 == $radio9 || $radio6 == $radio10)
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else if($radio7 == $radio1 || $radio7 == $radio2 || $radio7 == $radio3 || $radio7 == $radio4 || $radio7 == $radio5 || $radio7 == $radio6 || $radio7 == $radio8 || $radio7 == $radio9 || $radio7 == $radio10)
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else if($radio8 == $radio1 || $radio8 == $radio2 || $radio8 == $radio3 || $radio8 == $radio4 || $radio8 == $radio5 || $radio8 == $radio6 || $radio8 == $radio7 || $radio8 == $radio9 || $radio8 == $radio10)
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else if($radio9 == $radio1 || $radio9 == $radio2 || $radio9 == $radio3 || $radio9 == $radio4 || $radio9 == $radio5 || $radio9 == $radio6 || $radio9 == $radio7 || $radio9 == $radio8 || $radio9 == $radio10)
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else if($radio10 == $radio1 || $radio10 == $radio2 || $radio10 == $radio3 || $radio10 == $radio4 || $radio10 == $radio5 || $radio10 == $radio6 || $radio10 == $radio7 || $radio10 == $radio8 || $radio10 == $radio9)
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
        else{

    //echo "this line waas called ". $_SESSION['catid'] . "vALUE". $_POST['submitsubcategory'];
    $answer->AddAnswerType( $_POST['answertype'], $radio1, $radio2, $radio3, $radio4, $radio5, $radio6, $radio7, $radio8, $radio9, $radio10); // adds the subcategory to the 'category' table
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="0; '.$url.'">';
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: there's no mysql here and the form (html). In any case; check for errors on the query.

Comment: I think the mysql is in the AddAnswerType function. I guess?

Comment: check whats inside $radio1 - 10 and why do you do so many ifs? you could do this with only one oO?

Comment: @Fred-ii- The amount of if-statements is scaring me :(

Comment: What does the function AddAnswerType function return?

Comment: *"not working"* that stands to get voted as such.

Comment: @icecub I know. You got to love a good mystery though ;-)

Comment: @Jola what exactly you want to achieve from this ,lot's of if else what is it's purpose.

Comment: @PhpDev Maybe; they're also using a class with methods; Lord only knows what those hold in store. Again; another good mystery.

Comment: your code is quite clumsy. The number of parameters you are parsing is quite alot. In your html form, parse the names as arrays, e.g <input name='answer[radio1]'. then in your function just do a $_POST['answer']

Comment: It's basically 10 textboxes in 1 form and their values can't be the same, atleast that's what I'm trying to achieve in my code but it's currently not working because I think my syntax for validation is wrong

Comment: @Jola see jeroen's answer (and/or others). If that doesn't work. you'll need to post a comment under it and add the relevant code for all this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- And they are textboxes! I'm going for the jackpot!

Comment: @jeroen That you are! However, really strange as to all that's mentioned/syntax used are "radios". *Hmm............*

Comment: Why can't you use AJAX! way better, faster, no page reloading!

Comment: I've just put the code to test by manually inserting unique values to each radio variable and it passed through perfectly. So the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @PhpDev  what would be the difference if he's using ajax? that suggestion have nothing to do with the reported "issue"

Comment: Yeah. OOps OP just accepted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in shorter way like this

```
<?php


$url='Settings.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submitanswertype'])) {

    $radio1 = $_POST['radio1'];
    $radio2 = $_POST['radio2'];
    $radio3 = $_POST['radio3'];
    $radio4 = $_POST['radio4'];
    $radio5 = $_POST['radio5'];
    $radio6 = $_POST['radio6'];
    $radio7 = $_POST['radio7'];
    $radio8 = $_POST['radio8'];
    $radio9 = $_POST['radio9'];
    $radio10 = $_POST['radio10'];
    $answerype = $_POST['answertype'];

    $narray = array_unique($_POST);

    $answer = new CategoryDAO();

        if(count($_POST)!=count($narray))
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
        }else{

    //echo "this line waas called ". $_SESSION['catid'] . "vALUE". $_POST['submitsubcategory'];
    $answer->AddAnswerType( $_POST['answertype'], $radio1, $radio2, $radio3, $radio4, $radio5, $radio6, $radio7, $radio8, $radio9, $radio10); // adds the subcategory to the 'category' table
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="0; '.$url.'">';
        }
} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you sir this worked for my situation! I don't know why someone downvoted your answer but I clicked the this answer is useful. Thanks again sir @Varun Malhotra

Comment: This is wrong: As there are other inputs in the form, there is no way of knowing if they have to be unique as well.

Comment: your welcome i also don't know way some one down vote for my answer any way's i am glad to help you thanks. :)

Comment: we didn't expected that! :)) that's why sometimes I feel I should leave so :))

Comment: @jeroen please read the question that no variable should have same value. :)

Comment: @VarunMalhotra Because, as jeroen pointed out, your code is going to cause issues. If the form sends any other data that isn't unique, your code will mess that up since you're assuming the entire POST request headers will be unique

Comment: that `count` on his answer does exactly the same thing.. how much programming to you know @VarunMalhotra ?

Comment: @VarunMalhotra The OP is only checking for the `radio` values, not for `submitanswertype`, `answertype`, etc.

Comment: see i only provide the solution for that code that was available in the question so please calm down :)

Comment: *"so please calm down"* - @VarunMalhotra I don't see anyone being "not calm" here. They're only giving their opinion. Btw; that was not my downvote.

Comment: :) see if i see some other variables that could be same but we have to ignore that then ill provide the code according to that but @matel mihai is pointing on my programing skill and what i know is that every programming needs the logics which gives you instant solution.

Comment: hey its bad to vote down somebody quation if your answer is not accepted.

Answer (score 7):

As you have noticed, your way of checking leads to a lot of code. Hard to maintain and impossible for any of us to troubleshoot.

You could make it a lot easier (also to debug...) if you use arrays in your form:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio[]" value="some_value">
                              ^^ Now radio is an array.
```

Now you will have an array in `$_POST['radio']` and checking for duplicate values is very easy:

```
if (count($_POST['radio']) !== count(array_unique($_POST['radio']))) {
    // duplicate values
}
```

Comment: If this one solves this mystery, you'll definitely get my vote ;-) edit: others agree, so will I then.

Comment: Now, let's only hope the OP doesn't come back and say: *"It doesn't work"*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- To be honest, I didn't even check the code for problems, I just noticed the length...

Comment: This is better. instead of posting soo many input names. Array is the way!

Comment: Now.. the single problem i see here is the fact that there might be 10 different radio groups with different number of inputs for each group.. in that case your example will not work entirely but is for sure a better way to code as I already upvoted too

Comment: @MateiMihai "Radio groups"; real strange as to why the OP is using `<input>` with a `"text"` type though. Edit: wait... I think I'm wrong here.

Comment: @MateiMihai It would need some modifications for different situations, but with the OP's use of "names" this would seem a good start :-)

Comment: i hope OP is using type radio.

Comment: @jeroen why inputs though? I mean; the OP can change those to radios, it's the `[]` that would make this all get stitched together.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I have changed to radio buttons, but the idea is the same.

Comment: @jeroen *"but the idea is the same"* - which is why I wrote *"I mean; the OP can change those to radios, it's the [] that would make this all get stitched together"* ;-) and if that still doesn't solve it, they can take me up on the comment I wrote to them under their question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know. I changed it for anybody else stumbling in here :-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- The wrong one at that. Probably. Maybe. Depending on the other input fields...

Comment: @jeroen *"C'est la vie!"* - Btw; I removed all the irrelevant tags for it. The only thing left is "php". Cheers; enjoy your coffee/day.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Cheers, you too!

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution.

there is **syntax error**.

in **php** **elseif** write **together** not separately .

```
elseif($radio2 == $radio1 || $radio2 == $radio3 || $radio2 == $radio4 || $radio2 == $radio5 || $radio2 == $radio6 || $radio2 == $radio7 || $radio2 == $radio8 || $radio2 == $radio9 || $radio2 == $radio10)
{
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Cannot insert duplicate option name")';
            echo '</script>';
}
```

try it.

Comment: this has no effect on the outcome